# AppWidget is frozen before message has been sent or recieved. How to initiate the intent before messages are sent?

Tags: java, android, widget

So appwidget is fixed after some help on here but before any message has been sent or received the intent to launch the ChatRoomActivity doesn't work.

How could I set it up so it's intent launches the activity before any message  has been sent/received(obviously it would have no message but it has a textView saying click to open chat..etc).

my code:

```
public class ProTalkWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String ACTION_BROADCASTWIIDGET = "ACTION_BROADCASTWIIDGET";
    public static final String PROTALK_APPWIDGET_UPDATE = "PROTALK_APPWIDGET_UPDATE";

    private final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    public static final String USER_ID = "userId";
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String msgReceiverId;


    private void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                 final int appWidgetId) {

        //Construct the RemoteViews object
        final RemoteViews views;
        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.pro_talk_widget);





        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProTalkWidget.class);

        intent.setAction(ACTION_BROADCASTWIIDGET);

        context.sendBroadcast(intent);

        appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);



        if(PROTALK_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())){

            Log.i("onReceive", "getting onReceived!");


            handleMsg(intent, context);


        }
        }


    private void handleMsg(final Intent intent, final Context ctx){

        msgReceiverId = intent.getStringExtra("receiverId");


        if(msgReceiverId!=null) {


            String my_Id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

            final RemoteViews views;
            views = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.pro_talk_widget);


            DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            Query query = rootRef.child("Messages").child(my_Id).child(msgReceiverId).limitToLast(1);
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Messages messages = ds.getValue(Messages.class);
                        String message = messages.getMessage();
                        String from = messages.getFrom();
                        Log.d("TAG", message + "+" + from);
                        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_message, message);
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ctx, ChatRoomActivity.class);
                        if(msgReceiverId != null)

                            mainIntent.putExtra("profile_view_userId", msgReceiverId);
                        mainIntent.putExtra("username", "Ben");
                        PendingIntent mainPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, REQUEST_CODE, mainIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


                        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_layout, mainPendingIntent);


                        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(ctx).updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(ctx, ProTalkWidget.class), views);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
```

[image: AppWidget ()]

Please note intent and displaying message works after chatroomactivity has been opened and message sent.

ChatroomActivity

```
public class ChatRoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = ChatRoomActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK = 1;
    private String msgReceiverId;
    private String msgReceiverName;
    private static final int TOTAL_ITEMS = 10;
    private int currentPage = 1;
    private TextView chatUserName;
    private TextView chatLastSeen;
    private CircleImageView chatProfileImg;
    private DatabaseReference rootRef;
    private ImageView sendMsgBtn;
    private EditText textInputET;
    private RecyclerView usersMsgList;
    private final List<Messages> messagesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    //private TabsPagerAdapter.MessagesAdapter messagesAdapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private int ITEM_POSITION = 0;
    private String lastKey;
    private String prevKey;
    private StorageReference imgStorage;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    String msgSenderId;

    Toolbar appBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES){
            setTheme(R.style.darkTheme);
        }else{
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_room);
        rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        msgSenderId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        msgReceiverId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("profile_view_userId");

        msgReceiverName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
        sendMsgBtn = findViewById(R.id.input_text_btn);
        textInputET = findViewById(R.id.input_text);
        ProTalkApplication.getInstance().messagesAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter.MessagesAdapter(messagesList);
        usersMsgList = findViewById(R.id.users_messages_list);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        usersMsgList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        usersMsgList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        usersMsgList.setAdapter(ProTalkApplication.getInstance().messagesAdapter);
        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        imgStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        fetchMsg();

        Intent widgetIntent = new Intent(this,ProTalkWidget.class);

        //send value
        widgetIntent.putExtra("receiverID", msgReceiverName);
        sendBroadcast(widgetIntent);


        appBar = findViewById(R.id.chat_appbar);
        setSupportActionBar(appBar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View actionBarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_bar, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);

        chatUserName = findViewById(R.id.chat_profile_name);
        chatLastSeen = findViewById(R.id.chat_last_seen);
        chatProfileImg = findViewById(R.id.chat_profile_img);

        chatUserName.setText(msgReceiverName);

        sendMsgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendMsg();

            }
        });

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                currentPage++;
                ITEM_POSITION = 0;

                fetchMoreMsg();

            }
        });


        rootRef.child("User").child(msgReceiverId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String online = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString().trim();
                final String userImg = dataSnapshot.child("thumbnail").getValue().toString();

                if (online.equals("true")) {
                    chatLastSeen.setText(R.string.online);
                } else {
                    GetTimeAgo getTime = new GetTimeAgo();
                    long lastSeen = Long.parseLong(online);
                    String lastOnline = getTime.getTimeAgo(lastSeen, getApplicationContext());
//
                    chatLastSeen.setText(lastOnline);
                }

                Picasso.get().load(userImg).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.defaultimg).into(chatProfileImg, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                        Picasso.get().load(userImg)
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.defaultimg).into(chatProfileImg);

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });


    }

    private void fetchMoreMsg() {

        DatabaseReference msgRef = rootRef.child("Messages").child(msgSenderId).child(msgReceiverId);

        Query msgQuery = msgRef.orderByKey().endAt(lastKey).limitToLast(10);
        msgQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                String messageKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                if (!prevKey.equals(messageKey)) {

                    messagesList.add(ITEM_POSITION++, messages);

                } else {
                    prevKey = lastKey;
                }

                if (ITEM_POSITION == 1) {

                    lastKey = messageKey;


                }


                ProTalkApplication.getInstance().messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(10, 0);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

    private void fetchMsg() {

        DatabaseReference msgRef = rootRef.child("Messages").child(msgSenderId).child(msgReceiverId);

        Query msgQuery = msgRef.limitToLast(currentPage * TOTAL_ITEMS);

        msgQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                String messageKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                ITEM_POSITION++;


                if (ITEM_POSITION == 1) {


                    lastKey = messageKey;
                    prevKey = messageKey;

                }


                messagesList.add(messages);
                ProTalkApplication.getInstance().messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                usersMsgList.scrollToPosition(messagesList.size() - 1);

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChatRoomActivity.this, ProTalkWidget.class);
                intent.setAction(ProTalkWidget.PROTALK_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
                intent.putExtra("senderId", msgSenderId);
                intent.putExtra("receiverId", msgReceiverId);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMsg() {
        String msgTxt = textInputET.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(msgTxt)) {
            Toast.makeText(ChatRoomActivity.this, R.string.please_write_a_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            String sender_message_ref = "/Messages/" + msgReceiverId + "/" + msgSenderId;
            String receiver_message_ref = "/Messages/" + msgSenderId + "/" + msgReceiverId;
            DatabaseReference userMsgKey = rootRef.child("Messages").child(msgReceiverId)
                    .child(msgSenderId).push();

            String push_id = userMsgKey.getKey();
            Map msgTxtBody = new HashMap();
            msgTxtBody.put("message", msgTxt);
            msgTxtBody.put("from", msgSenderId);
            msgTxtBody.put("seen", false);
            msgTxtBody.put("type", "text");
            msgTxtBody.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
            Map msgBodyDetails = new HashMap();
            msgBodyDetails.put(sender_message_ref + "/" + push_id, msgTxtBody);
            msgBodyDetails.put(receiver_message_ref + "/" + push_id, msgTxtBody);

            rootRef.updateChildren(msgBodyDetails, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    if (databaseError != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                    textInputET.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks Again!!!

Comment: Just call `setOnClickPendingIntent()` on the `RemoteViews` you're creating initially with an `Intent` for `ChatRoomActivity`.

Comment: Thanks so Much Mike!!!!

Comment: but once it has lauched then if you close app again on 2nd launch it crashes, why? is it to do with putExtras?

Comment: I can't be certain, since I don't know what your `Activity` code is, but that's what I would guess. You're attaching several extras to the other `Intent` you create in `ProTalkWidget`, so I would imagine your `Activity` is expecting those, and possibly trying to use them unconditionally. You'll have to make sure those extras are actually on the `Intent` before using them.

Comment: plus do I set the pendingIntent in updateAppwidget?

Comment: added ChatRoomActivity see fetchMsg() method please...Thanks again Mike...

Comment: Well, you'll have to look at [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the cause of the crash with certainty, but when you set the `Intent` without any extras, `msgReceiverId` and `msgReceiverName` will both be null, and I would bet that `rootRef.child("User").child(msgReceiverId)` will crash if you pass it null. As mentioned, you need to make sure those values are not null before you use them. If they are null, then you'll need to skip the code that uses them.